# Surfaces generated by minimum-weight triangulations

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, graph-theory, triangulations

The [minimum-weight triangulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum-weight_triangulation) of simple polygons can be efficiently calculated in  $O(n^3)$ time by [dynamic programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming), while it is $\text{NP-hard}$ for pointsets in general.

Looking at the dynamic-programming algorithm, one sees that it also works for Hamilton cycles in symmetric graphs with arbitrarily weighted edges.

> **Question:**
>
> what are the differential-geometric properties of surfaces that  result from calculating the minimum-weight triangulations of points that are distributed along a rectifiable closed 3D curve as the number of points increases and the maximal distance between neighboring points tends to $0$; will that be the minimum-area surface defined by the curve?

Comment: This way you can get only ruled surfaces, and minimal surfaces are not ruled in general. So for sure one can not get an area-minimizing surface in the limit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that a minimum edge-weight triangulation would not in general lead to a minimum-area surface. Instead a minimum-area triangulation might.

There is a considerable literature on triangulations of 3D polygons. You probably know that triangulating a 3D polygon is NP-hard (a 1995 result).

Here is one relatively recent paper that cites many others.
The leftmost images in their figure minimize the area.
In general, the resulting surface is quite sensitive to the
function optimized, which suggests your min-area hypothesis/hope may not be realized.

> Zou, Ming; Ju, Tao; and Carr, Nathan, "Delaunay-restricted Optimal Triangulation of 3D Polygons." Report Number: WUCSE-2012-45 (2012).
> [PDF download](https://openscholarship.wustl.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1083&context=cse_research).

[image: ZTC]

Comment: I had asked for closed 3D curves, so the articles related to 3D polygons perfectly fit my question.

Comment: @ManfredWeis: Oh, sorry, I missed "closed." So in fact directly relevant. Will edit.

Comment: I just noticed a little misinterpretation of what triangulating a 3D polygon means; citing from "On Triangulating 3-Dimensional Polygons" by Barequet, Dickersen and Eppstein: "A three-dimensional polygon is triangulable if it has a non-selfintersecting triangulation which defines a simply connected 2-manifold". That is however more restrictive than blindly applying the dynamic programming algorithm to the distance graph of a 3D polygon (what I had originally in the back of my mind).

Comment: @ManfredWeis: Yes, the NP-hardness depends on non-self-intersection: "If we allow self-intersecting triangulations (in contrast with our definition), then computing the optimal triangulation can be done (in cubic time) by applying a simple dynamic-programming procedure."